# Something appears to be corrupting my kernel.log file, causing 5-10 second lock ups. What gives?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, error, hfs

**The Problem:**
Lately, every 10 minutes or so, my MacbookPro8,2 has been freezing up for 5-10 seconds. During those 5-10 seconds, video/audio content stops playing, all applications lock up, and hitting Cmd+Opt+Esc doesn't bring up the Force Quit Applications window until after the lock up passes and everything starts working/playing again.

**The Plot Thickens:**
I decided to check kernel.log in Console.app, but when I clicked on it, my system immediately froze up in the same manner as described above. It turned out that any time I tried to view kernel.log in the Console, my system would freeze up. Eventually, I got it to open in TextEdit (this took way longer than it should have. It seemed like performing any action on kernel.log caused a 5-10 second lock up), and I found some rather alarming lines:

```
hfs_clonefile: cluster_read failed - 5  
disk0s2: I/O error.
```

The timestamps for these entries (there were many) were coincident with the lock ups. So at this point I was terrified that my hard drive was dying, but I kept thinking about how messing with kernel.log would immediately cause a lock up (and an I/O error in the file) while performing actions on other files would not.

So I deleted kernel.log... **and it fixed everything.** The system eventually recreated the file, and I found that this new kernel.log opened instantly in Console, and one, two, three, five hours later, no lock ups had occurred, and no I/O errors had appeared in the log.

A month later, I hadn't had a single lock up... until a few days ago. I checked the kernel log again, and sure enough, another I/O error. Sure enough, Console wouldn't show me the log. And just like last time, deleting the log fixed everything.

**Diagnosis?**
It would appear that something is corrupting *the file that tells me if my files are corrupted.* But I'm out of ideas in terms of how to figure out why this is happening. What do you think?

Also, I ran Apple Hardware Test (with extended testing) and all the Disk Utility verifications when I first noticed the I/O errors, and everything came back normal. (S.M.A.R.T. Status: Verified, too)

Comment: Several things: Have you tried a 3rd party SMART tool like SMART Utility (free to demo)?  According to this ancient entry on "MacRumors Forum"(http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=586999) it may be a permissions issue.

Comment: Just to add to this conversation since I have never found a good solution. my MBP also has this issue, Opening Console.app causes my machine to become unresponsive for long periods of time I too ended up deleting _ALL_ of my logs and it solved the issue for about a month. I have reimaged, spinrited and even replaced my drive and it keeps happening.

Comment: It's still happening with a new drive? I believe you, but I don't see how that's possible. I "solved" my problem by buying a SSD and installing the base OSX there, and then repurposed the troublesome drive (the drive did fail [SeaTools](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/) tests) as a storage drive. I've had zero problems since then.